# Parse Javascript SDK not logging into Facebook

Tags: javascript, facebook

I'm using Parse Javascript SDK to authenticate to Facebook and even though I get a success after login, my Facebook session is not created. Here is the code I use,

```
 <div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
  // Additional JS functions here
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
      Parse.FacebookUtils.init({
            appId      : 'xxxx', // Facebook App ID
           // channelUrl : '//WWW.YOUR_DOMAIN.COM/channel.html', // Channel File
            status     : true, // check login status
            cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow Parse to access the session
            xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
          });
  };

  // Load the SDK Asynchronously
  (function(d){
     var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
     ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
   }(document));

  function fLogin() {

        Parse.FacebookUtils.logIn(null, {
              success: function(user) {
                  alert("login success with user " + JSON.stringify(user));
                if (!user.existed()) {
                  alert("User signed up and logged in through Facebook!");
                } else {
                  alert("User logged in through Facebook!");
                }
                //FB.api('/me', function(response) {
                //  alert("got fb me api=" + JSON.stringify(response));
                //});

              },
              error: function(user, error) {
                alert("User cancelled the Facebook login or did not fully authorize.");
              }
            });
    }
</script>


<button class="btn-facebook btn-large" onclick="fLogin();"><img src="./img/fb_icon.png"> <span class="btn-facebook-text">Login with Facebook</span></button>
```

After the popup window opens and I log into Facebook, I get the console message "login success with user " and I can see the access token.  However when I try to call FB.api ("/me")... I get an error saying Invalid access token from Facebook.. And When I go back to Facebook, I see that it didn't log me into Facebook either...

If I replace this whole code with FB.init() and FB.login() it works just fine.. Its when I replace it with Parse FacebookUtils that I get the error.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: FYI, I've initialized Parse correctly before this code.

Comment: Don't parse provide a customer support?

Comment: Yeah, I've logged it there as well.  Just waiting for help.